# String references comparison in Rust

Tags: string, rust, comparison

I just confirmed how the `Vec::contains` works. I wrote code below and it looked working fine.

But I don't know why it works because it compares `&String` types. Does it mean String comparison works even they aren't dereferenced?

```rust
struct NewStruct {
    string_vec: Vec<Option<String>>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut mys = NewStruct {
        string_vec: Vec::<Option<String>>::new(),
    };
    mys.string_vec.push(Some("new array".to_string()));
    let ref_st = mys.string_vec.iter().filter(|o|o.is_some()).map(|o|o.as_ref().unwrap()).collect::<Vec<&String>>();
    println!("result:{:?}", ref_st.contains(&&("some string".to_string())));
    println!("result:{:?}", ref_st.contains(&&("new array".to_string())));
    println!("Hello, world!");
    f64::from(1234_u64 as i32);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are Rust's exact auto-dereferencing rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules)

Comment: @Jmb this is not because auto-dereferencing, but because equality on references compares the values.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Reference comparison on references in Rust *always* compares the values, never the addresses. This is true not just for `&String` but *for any* `&T`.

For example this does not compile because `Foo` does not implement `PartialEq` even though I'm only comparing references:

```
struct Foo;

fn main() {
    let a = Foo;
    let b = Foo;

    assert!(&a == &b);
}
```

```
error[E0369]: binary operation `==` cannot be applied to type `&Foo`
 --> src/main.rs:7:16
  |
7 |     assert!(&a == &b);
  |             -- ^^ -- &Foo
  |             |
  |             &Foo
  |
  = note: an implementation of `std::cmp::PartialEq` might be missing for `&Foo`
```

The `PartialEq` implementation on references is

```rust
impl<'_, '_, A, B> PartialEq<&'_ B> for &'_ A where
    A: PartialEq<B> + ?Sized,
    B: ?Sized,
```

You can see that checking `&A == &B` requires to be able to do `A == B`.